# find the minimum (double) in c++

Tags: c++, function, double, void, minimum

I just started learning c++ and I wrote a code to find the minimum with int values and now I have to do it with doubles and I got wrong! please let me know how to fix it!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void findminval (double num1, double num2) {
double minval;
if (num1<num2){
    minval=num1;
} else {
    minval=num2;
}

}
void findminval (int num1, int num2) {
int minval;
if (num1<num2){
    minval=num1;
} else {
    minval=num2;
}

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int num1,num2;
    cout<<"Enter Two Numbers"<<endl;
    cin>>num1>>num2;
    int minimumvalue = findminval(int num1,int num2);
    cout<<minimumvalue<<endl;

double num1,num2;
    cout<<"Enter Two Numbers"<<endl;
    cin>>num1>>num2;
    double minimumvalue = findminval(num1,num2);
    cout<<minimumvalue<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you "get wrong"? Was it a compiling error? If so, what line is it happening in?

Comment: Your functions have the return type `void` which means they do not report a result. You should read about [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return)ing.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are missing an explicit `return` value (you also can't change the type of a variable in the same scope, so your compiler will complain when it reaches `double num1,num2;`).

As a bare minimum you need to write

```
double findminval(double num1, double num2){
    double minval;
    if (num1 < num2){
        minval = num1;
    } else {
        minval = num2;
    }
    return minval;
}
```

although you could simplify perhaps at the expense of this being harder to debug, to

```
double findminval(double num1, double num2){
    if (num1 < num2){
        return num1;
    } else {
        return num2;
    }
}
```

or even

```
double findminval (double num1, double num2){
    return num1 < num2 ? num1 : num2;
}
```

Note then that you could *templatise* this so you don't need two functions:

```
template<typename Y> Y findminval(const Y& num1, const Y& num2){
    return num1 < num2 ? num1 : num2;
}
```

Note that I'm now passing by `const` reference to obviate possible value copies. Now you see we are stumbling upon `std::min`. There's one final point to consider: the "etiquette" is to return the first argument if the parameters are equal. That's to preserve a *signed zero* of floating point, or even an integral type in a 1's complement system. So this is probably the best thing to do, other than using `std::min`:

```
template<typename Y> Y findminval(const Y& num1, const Y& num2){
    return num1 <= num2 ? num1 : num2;
}
```